# RESTeasy service input parameter is empty

Tags: java, web-services, rest, resteasy

I have written the below resteasy service and taking the request parameter from the rest URL as /{categoryId} and input it to my method as String categoryID.

```
    @Path("/getArticlebyCat/{categoryID}")
    @PermitAll
    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Response searchArticleByCategoryID(String categoryID) {
        List<Article> articleList = new ArrayList();
        try {
            System.out.println("categoryID>>>"+categoryID);
            articleList = searchService.findArticleByCategoyID(categoryID);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.getLogger(RestServiceOne.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Response response = Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(articleList).build();
        return response;
    }
```

But from the service logs, I dont get the **categoryID** value passed via rest call.it comes empty. please help me to sort this out.
Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> @PathParam is a parameter annotation which allows you to map variable
>   URI path fragments into your method call.

So you have to use `@PathParam`annotation here.

```
@Path("/getArticlebyCat/{categoryID}")
@PermitAll
@GET
@Produces("application/json")
public Response searchArticleByCategoryID(@PathParam("categoryID")String categoryID) {

}
```

[More on Path Params](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.0.0.GA/userguide/html/_PathParam.html)

Comment: Thank you, this one worked! but my question is I also have one more method similar to this without the @PathParam annotation, but it works. could you please tell my how that is working?

Comment: Please update the question with that method, i can look into it

Answer (score 1):

Could you please post your URL too, as i can see you are requesting for get method , You should use it something like @PathParam(String categoryId).